# How to write this quantified logical expression correctly?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, quantifiers

I have to construct a quantified logical expression from statement: "Each circle with center in 0 in complex plane is made of points, which have the same absolute value".

My attempt is the following:
$$(\forall \mathcal{K} \in \mathbb{C}, \mathcal{K} = \{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z| < r, r \in \mathbb{C}\})((a\in \mathcal{K} \land b \in \mathcal{K}) \implies (|a| = |b|)).$$

Is it correct? Shall I declare what are $a$ and $b$ somewhere?

Comment: This is a definition or a theorem?

Comment: Just an excercise to teach us writing logical expressions with quantifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Taking
$$\forall K(\text{$K$ is a complex circle with center in $0$}\iff\exists r>0(K=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|=r\}))$$
as definition, then
$$\forall K(\text{$K$ is a complex circle with center in $0$}\implies\forall a\in K\forall b\in K(|a|=|b|))$$
is a theorem.